# Convert unicode string with PHP

Tags: php, unicode, unicode-string

I have this string which I'm fetching with an API call. It's an email subject line read directly from gmail.

```
=?UTF-8?Q?200_drones_and_a_flying_Fer?= =?UTF-8?Q?Rari_=F0=9F=8F=8E_(Typical_Drake_=F0=9F=99=8F=F0=9F=8F=BB)?=
```

Code:

```
$inbox = imap_open('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX',$username,$password);
$overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
$subject = $overview[0]->subject;
```

It should look like this:

```
200 drones and a flying Ferrari  (Typical Drake )
```

Is there a way to convert the first to the second in PHP so I can display it in a standard web page?

Already tried

```
utf8_decode("=?UTF-8?Q?200_drones_and_a_flying_Fer?= =?UTF-8?Q?Rari_=F0=9F=8F=8E_(Typical_Drake_=F0=9F=99=8F=F0=9F=8F=BB)?=");
```

But this just prints out the string with no changes.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [iconv_mime_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-mime-decode.php)

Comment: well that is a lot cleaner than this function I cooked up as I waited function fixEmojis($string)

{

 
 $string = str_replace(" =?UTF-8?Q?", "", $string);
 $string = str_replace("=?UTF-8?Q?", "", $string);

 $string = str_replace("?= ", "", $string);
 $string = str_replace("?=", "", $string);

 $string = str_replace("_", " ", $string);



 return urldecode(str_replace("=", "%", $string));

}